How to share Dolphin icons for Windows share
I have an old Windows 7 machine that I use for file sharing. I access the drives shared from this machine from two Kubuntu machines. I would like to use the same icons on both machines. I can't get my chosen icons to "stick" on both Linux machines. If i set the icons in Dolphin on machine1 and then open Dolphin on machine2, I get the question mark icon. If I then set my preferred icons on machine2 and open Dolphin on machine1, I get the question mark icon. The Linux machines are using separate accounts on the Windows server. I have tried using different icons in Dolphin, but choosing any custom icon on one machine resets the icon to the question mark icon on the other. How can I use the same icons on both machine for these Windows shares?
